# Solving the double integral with $|y-2x|\leq 0.1$ as boundary

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value

Question:

Solve the integral of $x$ with boundaries $|y-2x|\leq 0.1,
 0 \leq x \leq 1,     
0 \leq y \leq 1 $

What gave me trouble is the absolute value, I tried graphing it online and got a noncontinuous line, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $y \geq 2x$ and $2x \geq y$ separately.

Please see the sketch. You have to integrate over the area shaded in black.

Integrate over $dx$ first and then over $dy$ so you have to split it into two integrals otherwise you will have to split it into three.

$D1: 0 \leq x \leq \frac{y + 0.1}{2}, 0 \leq y \leq 0.1$

$D2: \frac{y - 0.1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{y + 0.1}{2}, 0.1 \leq y \leq 1$

[image]

Comment: thank you for this

Comment: You are welcome!